# Uncaught error java.net.UnknowHostException. Unable to resolve "exp.host". No address associated with hostname React Native

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

I am working in react-native only simulator using from android studio. after some update jdk I am getting this error. can somebody please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZWma.png)

Answer (score 3):

This error is due to the fact that the android emulator has no internet connection, how I fixed this was *by turning off the emulator and turning it on again*. This worked for me, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It happens if there is no internet connection. If the connection issue is only for the android emulator, rather than wasting time on fixing it, delete and recreate the same or new emulator. It works for me for most of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as mentioned by [OGECHUKWU MEPHORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67368431/8520849), `This error is due to the fact that the android emulator has no internet connection`.

In my case the problem was in Wi-Fi. After connecting to the mobile hotspot, the issue resolved. I tried re-create the virtual device but the issue was not resolved.